# unmarshal xml to object for a nested tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've got some generated classes from a 3rd party provider for their API - specifically Companies House (http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/)

I'm having trouble unmarshalling the parts of the response from the API. I can cast the object to a `GovTalkMessage` object, which contains a `Body` tag - but the underlying object I get back after unsmarshalling is a `ElementNSImpl` object instead of the expected pojo.

**Example**

I create a request like this one: http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/examples/companydetails_req.xml

And get a response like this one: http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/examples/companydetails_reply.xml

You can see in the reply that there is:

```
<Body>
<CompanyDetails xmlns="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/CompanyDetails-v2-1.xsd">
    ...
</Body>
```

So the contents of the Body (which is a `List<Object>` in the generated `GovTalkMessage` pojo) should have a `CompanyDetails` object in the first element of the list. I instead have `ElementNSImpl`.

Here's the marshalling code, which works fine - can send it to the API endpoint and comes back with an xml response like the example above:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(GovTalkMessage.class, CompanyDetailsRequest.class, CompanyDetails.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

InputStream in = Request.Post ... //omitted - send to server, get response

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
GovTalkMessage reply = (GovTalkMessage)unmarshaller.unmarshal(in); //ok
Object object = reply.getBody().getAny().get(0); 
//object is ElementNSImpl - should be CompanyDetails
```

Am I doing something wrong in the unmarshal?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

If I modify the `package-info.java` to have

```
namespace = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema"
```

instead of

```
namespace = "http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope"
```

then the unmarshal works. But I can't get **both** marshal into `GovTalkMessage` and unmarshal into `CompanyAppointments` to work, even if I specify it directy:

```
JAXBContext payloadContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CompanyAppointments.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = payloadContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.unmarshal((Node)message.getBody().getAny().get(0), CompanyAppointments.class).getValue();
```

This just gives me a `CompanyAppointments` with fields full of nulls.

Answer (score 0):

It seems namespace used for generating binding classes and one received in response are conflicted.

binding class and XML response will be  required to point out error here :).

I'll suggest you to use package name in place of classes for creating JAXBContext.

```
final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.something"...);
```

Comment: Thanks; response and request are in the OP, CompanyAppointments is just generated from http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/CompanyAppointments-v2-2.xsd ... Tried putting the package name in there to no affect, see my update - something to do with namespace of the root element i think